# Problems with CloudSim 1.4.0 / AWS

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I successfully launched CloudSim 1.4.0 on us-east-1a but when I attempt to launch a constellation i get the following error:

[image: Error message]

I have already requested to be allowed 12 GPU instances from Amazon as stated in [this](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/CloudSim/aws_setup) tutorial.  I got an email stating my request had been completed and closed, so I assume that I have the instances I ask for, but I still get this error. I have requested the allowance again just in case, but is there a chance this is an issue with CloudSim and not Amazon? Any idea what I should do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3108/problems-with-cloudsim-1.4.0-/-aws/) by [Nick Eckenstein](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/307/nick-eckenstein/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 59 on 2013-06-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The problem ended up being amazon's. I requested EC2 instances again, and it worked after they responded again.

---

Originally posted by [Nick Eckenstein](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/307/nick-eckenstein/) with karma: 59 on 2013-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1